# My texture is washed out in the render, but not in the preview

Tags: rendering, color-management

I'm making a mock-up of a poster for my portfolio, but for some reason the texture of the poster is really washed out in the render. The rest of the objects which are just materials (not externally created image textures) seem fine, but the textured image looks terrible.

[image: comparison]

It looks as intended in the render preview while editing, but not in the actual finished render.

This is in cycles render.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, I have added an answer, however this still seems to be a bug and should be reported to the bugtracker. Bugs should be easily reproducable though, so you should find out how to recreate your problem from scratch before comitting it.

Answer (score 4):

The viewport renderer and seems to evaluate overlapping faces differently. In your scene, three faces from different objects are at the same position. Simply moving your textured object in front of the others will solve the problem.

[image: overlapping objects]

---

<sup>On a side note, did you intend to connect a Normap Map output with a color input?</sup>
[image: normap map output connected to color input]